# Getting segmentation fault in Linux when running my C program

Tags: c, linux, simulation

I am trying to simulate the [cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29) command in [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux). I am getting a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) when I run my program.

For example:

```
./a.out a > b
```

`a` contains hello. I expect hello to be copied in `b`.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int f, fd, r;
    char buf[100];

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Error");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!strcmp(argv[2],">"))
        {
            f = open(argv[1],0,00777);

            if (f == -1)
                printf("no file");
            else
            {
                fd = creat(argv[3],00777);
                while( (r = read(f,buf,50)) > 0)
                    write(fd, buf, r);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting a segmentaion error?

I have a similar program where I open and create the file in the same manner, and that program is running, but this one is giving me a segmentation fault.

Comment: One of the many reasons why `gdb` was invented.

Comment: @WhozCraig - now if they can only move on to one of the many reasons gdb needs to improve and become more usable and friendly.

Comment: Don't waste your life hand-formatting code; use a computer program. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_(Unix)

Comment: @Duck All major IDEs have very good support for GDB, including visual handling of call-stack and variables.

Comment: i have just started using linux.
And i am having an short exam tommorrow so need this code to be working

Comment: Then `gdb` in combination with `-g` on your compile command-line args will some in quite handy.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg - I haven't used an IDE in ages because I find them cumbersome and am stuck with DDD.  But if what you say is true I will try one in a second.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joachim Pileborg's answer is obviously correct, just try to run your program as

```
./a.out a \> b
```

to prevent the shell from interpreting ">" as a redirection.

Comment: Thanks this worked.

I am unablt to unterstand that in earlier program i gave ./a.out a > b
its working fine in that program.
But not in this program isn't it weird.

Comment: Your program is still wrong, as other have said, in the argc test. If you want to access argv[3], you have to exit if argc < 4, not if argc < 2.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably because the redirection is handled by the shell and not by your program, so `argv[2]` is `NULL` and `argv[3]` does not exist.

However you should use a debugger to find out what is really happening. And then add proper error checking.

Comment: +1 for knowing the standard dictates `argv[argc]` is guaranteed NULL (you'd likely not be surprised how often that is construed as undefined).

Comment: i made  a similar program a week ago and its working fine. Dont know why am i getting this error in this program only

Comment: @ashwinbhy Then it's probably working because it's _similar_. Redirection and pipes are _always_ handled by the shell.

Comment: Its almost the same.
here i am checking only one condition in another program i made for ">>" etc.. its working fine on same pc right now i am comparing both i used exactly same things but this progrm not working

Comment: actually i dont know how to use debugger i am very new to linux.i have to execute 20 more programs before my test tommorrow so wil leave this for now.

Answer (score 4):

You can live without `gdb` here - but you have to start solving the problem in a structured manner:

- Don't take anything as granted. E.g., even if you call your program as `program > file`, don't assume that `argv` looks the way you assume, but check it by outputting each of them:

  ```
  printf("argc: %d\n", argc);
  printf("argv[0]: %s\n", argv[0]);
  printf("argv[1]: %s\n", argv[1]);
  printf("argv[2]: %s\n", argv[2]);
  printf("argv[3]: %s\n", argv[3]);
  // the se can be expressed better with a for loop - but I'll leave that as an exercise for you
  ```
- Only take things as granted what you have verified: if you know that `argc >= 2`, don't access `argv[2]` and/or `argv[3]`.
- Don't say

  ```
  if(argc<2)
  {
      printf("Error");
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  but

  ```
  if(argc<2) // according to the point before, better y3 or <4
  {
      printf("Too few command line arguments");
      return 1; // not 0; 0 would mean success
  }
  ```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, a program this simple gdb is over kill, a few quick prints will isolate the issue.

Comment: @Mike only as far as the OP understands that he'll find all the prints in a file named `b`, and not on the screen. Indeed, error (and debugging) messages should go to stderr instead of stdout.